# What does my computer do when I click 'Shut Down'?

Tags: shutdown

What does my computer do when I click [image: Power Cog Icon (System Devices Menu)] ▸ **Shut Down**? I mean, is it running a script? What is it running?

Comment: [This may give an advanced general Linux shutdown runlevel stuff](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/customizing-the-linux-bootup-and-shutdown-processes/1056248)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system then calls the command `shutdown`. Logins are prevented and all users are notified of the impending shutdown. The command has a parameter called `TIME`, which is how long until the shutdown occurs. When you use the shut down from the corner the argument is `now`. According to the manual page of shutdown, after time has elapsed the shutdown command sends a request to the init daemon which is what really shuts the system down for good.

To execute this same process yourself you can run the command:

```
sudo shutdown now
```

Comment: but when i run shutdown from terminal it wants root privileges

Comment: but when i click shutdown it didn't wan't password

Comment: yes but i want to know how to shutdown system from terminal without root privileges @Dymatic

Comment: You raise a good point. My guess is it tells the init daemon to quit directly. This way it does what shutdown does without actually having to run it. How you would go about telling init to do this is beyond my ability, however.

Comment: if you want the system to poweroff that should ideally be `sudo shutdown -P now` ;)

As for explaining why the desktop ask for credentials, it's because the X window system and the desktop are run with root privileges :)

Comment: jackweirdy:  X and Gnome should not be run with root privileges.